# Google Calendar API. Service Account. Access Token Expired. Refresh AT without RT

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get events from my Google Calendar using Service Account. I received Access Token:

> {"access_token":"ya29.AHES6ZR9o2-cut-Gg","expires_in":3600,"created":1366631471}

Now this token is expired and when I trying to get events, I get an error:

> The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.

I tried to find way to get a new access token in API documentation, but did not find anything suitable. And now I have a question: How I must refresh my access token?

Code that I use to access the calendar:

```
session_start();

require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME', 'numbers-and-letters@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
define('CLIENT_ID', 'numbers-and-letters.apps.googleusercontent.com');

define('KEY_FILE', '../../key.p12');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("app name");

$client->setUseObjects(true);

$client->setClientID(CLIENT_ID);

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

if (isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
 $client->setaccessType('offline');
} 
else 
{
  $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'),
    $key
  ));
}

try
{
  $cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
  $events = $cal->events->listEvents('numbers-and-letters@group.calendar.google.com');
print_r($events);
} catch (Exception $e) echo $e->getMessage();

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

Comment: Hi stan. Welcome to SO! Instead of adding the answer to your question as an addendum to the question, you should submit an answer to your own question and accept that one. It's totally fine to answer your own question. In addition, the question will no longer appear in the 'questions with no answers' section, which helps with filtering such questions. And of course, this way the answer is more visible for future users who have the same question as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I solved! To refresh Access Token without Refresh Token you want to call Google_Client class's method revokeToken()

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to refresh token is:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
{
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
```